Laravel - Validate if email already exists in table users
I have a simple Angular 16 login/register form;
when a user registers in my app, register data is sent via http request to my laravel backend, where i handle user registration.
before i create a new user, i validate if any other user previouslly registered uses the same email, and if so i must notify that email is not available anymore.
my problem comes from this validation. i have user A with email test@test.com stored on my DB but when i try to register another user, user B with same email, validator allows it and user is created again.
i encrypt email and some other sensitive data before i store it on my database using $casts.
UserModel
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $casts = [
        'name' => "encrypted",
        'email' => "encrypted",
        "phone_number" => "encrypted",
        "password" => "encrypted"
    ];
}

this is how i encrypt my data on users table;
then on my addUser function inside my UsersController i have:
public function addUser(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
        'name' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required|min:8',
        'passwordConfirmation' => 'required|same:password',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response(['error' => 'Account already exists.'], 401);
    }

    $existingUser = User::where('email', $request->input("email"))->first();

    if ($existingUser) {
        return response(['error' => 'Account already exists.'], 401);
    }

    $user = User::create([
        "name" => $request->input("name"),
        "email" => $request->input("email"),
        "phone_number" => $request->input("phone_number"),
        "password" => $request->input("password"),
        "user_type" => $request->input("user_type"),
    ]);

    return response($user, 200);
}

i have 2 different ways of validating if user email is already being used and still none of them work.
if anyone could help me figure out my mistake and provide a solution or suggestion i would be greatly appreciated.

It is not going to be possible to do this with encrptyed content, you would have to decrypt every email in your database each time you create a new user, it would be slow and buggy, and tbh unnecessary to encrypt an email address or users name

Agreeing with the previous comment, it's just not possible to do this in a scaleable.  Additionally, I can't imagine a use case where this is needed.  You should already have at rest encryption through your database which would provide you any regulatory compliance. You can should focus on trying to restrict access to your db if you are worried about this style of data breach.

@DevonRay i considered your suggestion of decrypting every email but as you said it would be resource heavy and slow. but wouldnt there be another way in laravel to achieve my needs? i really need email to be encrypted because of GPDR standards.

@RicardoCarneiro Perhaps, if you'd hash them, instead of encrypting?

As @cfkane mentioned, your encryption in transit and database encryption would be enough for GDPR compliance.

    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt; 
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;         
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
     
    public function addUser(Request $request){         
       $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),['email' => 
    'required|email',     'name' => 'required','password' 
     =>'required|min:8','passwordConfirmation' => 
    'required|same:password']);
         

  if ($validator->fails()){     
            return response(['error' => 'Invalid data.'], 400);
               }
     

 // Decrypt the encrypted email       
        $decryptedEmail = Crypt::decrypt($request->input('email'));
 
    // Check if the decrypted email already exists in the db             $existingUser = User::where('email', $decryptedEmail)->first();         if ($existingUser) {             return response(['error' => 'Account already exists.'], 401);         }
 
    $user = User::create([             "name" => $request->input("name"),             "email" => $decryptedEmail, // Use decrypted email for database insertion             "phone_number" => $request->input("phone_number"),             "password" => $request->input("password"),             "user_type" => $request->input("user_type"),         ]);
 
    return response($user, 200);     }

